# Comment styling in moderation tools breaks workflow

Tags: bug, design, moderator-abilities, moderator-tools

In the diamond moderator queue, the comment moderation tools have been broken from a workflow perspective since the change.

Here's the normal workflow:

- Open Comment Flags
- Put Mouse button over top comment
- Visually scan comments; clicking delete or moving horizontally to click 'dismiss'

There's no need to ever really move the mouse vertically; and only a need to move it horizontally if we need to decline a comment flag (which is very, very, rare).

Here's why it's broken:

[image]

Now, if a flagger leaves a large comment, it wraps around to the next line, and since the delete/edit/dismiss is positioned the way it is, it gets bumped down a line; meaning that if I were to click 'delete', the mouse cursor for when that comment disappears would be off line from the next comment.  The red arrow shows where it should be, the not-red arrow shows where it is.

The positioning is crucial in being able to work through the comment queue in an efficient manner.

Second issue (although this isn't as bad; it still messes with our workflow), is that a comment score for a flagged comment is vertically on the comment, instead of in the upper left corner (as it is everywhere else on the site):

[image]

Since we use the comment score as a barometer of the comment's usefulness, and all of the information we normally need is on the top line (the flag, the delete/dismiss, the date, and the score), having the score bumped down to the center means our eyes have to track to some place we're not used to, leading to less efficient comment flag clearing.

I recognize these seem like small things; but if you spend your day inside the moderation queue, these little frustrations add up quickly.

Comment: Neither arrow is red in the first image (two are green, one is blue).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I blame it [on my colorblindness](http://georgestocker.com/2010/02/01/the-web-hates-colorblind-people/).