# Answers Deleted from the moderator queue should not still show up

Tags: bug, flags, not-an-answer, moderator-tools

It used to be that when we deleted an answer from the moderator queue (for instance, one that was deleted from the 'not an answer' flag section), it would disappear. Now, it does not.

[image]

I'm also confused as to why it has `undelete post (1)` next to it, since I *just* deleted the post in all cases. There shouldn't be an undelete vote that quickly.

Two bugs:

- A post we delete through the course of clicking 'Delete answer' from the "Not an answer" flag queue should disappear once we delete it. We have 50 items per page, it's easier (as [I indicated earlier](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284157/comment-styling-in-moderation-tools-breaks-workflow)) to keep the mouse in one place than it is to move the mouse for each post (It's also faster to keep the mouse in one place).
- The `undelete post (1)` should either be made more clear what the `1` refers to; the tooltip simply says `undelete post`.

Comment: On smaller sites, it's nice to have them stick around so you don't have to dig for a link if you make a mistake. Perhaps they could collapse like they do now, and have the page autoscroll to the next flag? That way you wouldn't have to move the mouse, and you'd still have the option of fixing a mistake easily.

Comment: @Undo Easily getting to mistakes I made is another bone of contention -- I don't think we should try to make the moderator queue do too many things, it feels like it should be for clearing flags. we do need an easy way to see our mistakes, but I don't think we should make the queue do two things.

Comment: I've actually found this useful when I accidentally clicked the delete button when I meant to click a different button. It's easy to quickly undelete it again without having to go track it down. Although, some better organization and consistency with displaying those buttons might keep me from doing that. But I don't remember it ever completely removing the post from the page when you delete. It's only ever done that for me when you manually dismiss the flags on the post.

Comment: @animuson Interesting; I always thought it did. I do know that I have muscle memory to hit CMD+R (or Ctrl+R), and I have my left hand positioned there when I'm on the mod queue so I can clear it out.